# Briggs and Stratton "Just Check and Add, never change oil" engine

Tags: oil, small-engine, reliability

Recently a relative was bragging about their new mower, with a new Briggs and Stratton "Just Check and Add" engine, with no oil change recommendation.  Better than sliced bread.

I remember when a loud bang followed by a thud was heard from a neighbor's riding mower one Saturday morning.  His still shiny mower, about three years old, had thrown a rod.  The oil sump was dry.  When asked, he said that no one told him he ever had to add oil.

That memory ran through my head with the pitching of the Just Check and Add engine.

Then I thought about it, and wondered just how often people didn't even check the oil on their mowers.  Perhaps on some it got changed at the annual "servicing" from a local small engine shop.

Probably better to have some oil, even if it is old, than none.

What is the track record on the B&S engines which are being marketed as "Just Check and Add"?  Are the engine failures lower than on other similar engines, without the same marketing hype?

Comment: The real issues are twofold: 1) poor maintenance and 2) common sense is getting rarer...  Like the one about the motorist who goes into the autoshop wanting some "710" for the engine....

Comment: Sounds like a great idea to sell more mowers.

Comment: I've been doing that with my Yardman push mower since I bought it in 1992.  Though, I do change the air filter and spark plug yearly.

Answer (score 1):

I have one. I used it for first year hard.  I pay my rent by mowing lawns for landlord - I mow 9 yards and a vacant lot.  After a year of hot dusty mowing I went to change oil and noticed placard.  Mower hasn't used a drop of oil and the original oil still looks like pure honey.  Even smells like new oil.  I'm impressed!

Comment: That is impressive.  I wonder how the engine is different?